# Adobe PDF form checkbox with "Custom calculation script"

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I am trying to create an interactive PDF to calculate prices based on weight and a checkbox for each line which should set the calculated price in that line to 0 if unchecked.
This is where I am at right now, but it is not working:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwqfY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Supporting previous comments, it would be best to make a sample showing just what you want to accomplish, and the way you have set it up at the moment. The image posted does not have sufficient information, to determine what happens (or does not happen).